# How to write code data into a text file

Tags: java, save, text-files

I just did a simple code which takes user name and phone number and save those into an arraylist by creating object. I want to save those information (name and phonenumber) into a text file so that all old information I can get again. How do I do it? Here is my code ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class manager {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <objectclass> Test = new ArrayList <objectclass> ();


        public void mainloop() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            String x;

            System.out.println("Please Select your option");
            System.out.println("............................");
            System.out.println("1 ADD NAME AND NUMBER\n2 SEARCH NAME AND NUMBER \n0 EXIT");
            System.out.println("............................");

            x = input.nextLine();

            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                break;
            }
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                String Name;
                String Number;

                System.out.println("Please Enter your Name below");
                Name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter your Number below");
                Number = input.nextLine();

                objectclass objectclassObject = new objectclass(Name, Number);
                Test.add(objectclassObject);
            }
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                String y;
                System.out.println("*** Enter your Name below for search ***");
                y = input.nextLine();

                for (objectclass p : Test) {
                    String z = p.getName();
                    if (z.equalsIgnoreCase(y)) {
                        System.out.println("Your Name is: " + p.getName() + "\nYour Number is: " + p.getNumber());
                        System.out.println("");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Contact not Found!\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save all name and number that I store in arraylist into a text file ... how can I do it?

I tried this so far but don't know what to do next ... 
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class creatfile {

private Formatter x;

public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("testkyo");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("you have an error");
    }
}
public void addRecord(){
    x.format();
}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing this data into a file? just have a look at java.io package, you have all the information there.

Comment: [Lesson: Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

Comment: i tried this so far ....
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class creatfile {

    private Formatter x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Formatter("testkyo");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("you have an error");
        }
    }
    public void addRecord(){
        x.format();
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
... now dont know what to do ...

Comment: ops sorry ... editing my post

Comment: just something i thought worth mentioning : you need to learn proper java "annotation"  ... for example objectclass is a class so u should name it ObjectClass , might sound irrelevant but will really help you later on ;)

Comment: i will try to keep that in mind :D~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize an object in order to save it onto the file .

[here's a tutorial on how to do it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm), its really simple.

When you serialize an object you can write it onto a file and then load it as it is from there .

EDIT :

example on how you could use this here , i guess the ObjectClass is the thing u want to save so :

```
class ObjectClass implements Serializable {
 String name;
 String number;
 //constructor , setters , getters  and w.e functions .

public static void main (String args[]){
try{    
 ObjectClass test = new ObjectClass("test",2);
 File f = new File("path to file");
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
 out.writeObject(test); // this will write the object as it is onto the file
 out.close();
}catch(Exception ex){}

    }

 }
```

you wont be able to read the data cuz its serialised , but u can load them as objects like so :

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new File("path to file"));
ObjectClass test =(ObjectClass) in.readObject(); // u have to cast from Object to Objectclass
```

Comment: can you please show me how can i use serialize my code? i cant understand that tutorial properly

Comment: i might have understood your question wrong , you wanted to write them as text but i got confused by the title "code data" , i thought you want to write the objects ... but still its a good thing to learn. I'll edit the answer for you if you decide to use it :)

Comment: i want to save name and number which i get from user input and want to save them into a text file. when i close my code all user inputs are gone ... i want to keep those user inputs. sorry my english is not that good ... may be i made some confusion :s~

Comment: my solution doesnt write text files it writes them as serialised objects ... if u want to write text data use JosEdu solution from above

Comment: well as i can understand by reading some tutorial ... serialization is a better way to save code data ... it stores whole data so that can be use later ... nice stuff. :D~

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./output.txt"));
        writer.write("Hello World");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will write "Hello World" in the text file named: "output.txt".

Check the java I/O api.

You can find a lot of tutorials on the web about this, like:

[Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

[Creating, Writing, Reading files using Java Files API of Java 7](http://www.javabeat.net/creating-writing-reading-java-files-api-java-7/)

Answer (score 0):

what you propably want is an `ObjectOutputstream` writing your ArrayList to a file via an `FileOutputStream` when the porgram is exiting and reading the Arraylist with the coresponding InputStreams. See the links below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html